# Rebus: Is it possible to have mulitple Sagas with the same IHandleMessages type

Tags: rebus

Is it possible to have two or more Sagas that handle the same message type?

For example two sagas that both implement IHandleMessages?
Does this work for all saga storages or only some of them?

Update:

I've tested I have two sagas (SendSMSSaga and SendEmailSaga)  both Implements the same IHandleMessages (seperate IAmInitiatedBy commands) the only thing that happens in the first handle is:

```
  if (!IsNew) return;

            Data.Command = message;
            Data.Id = message.SagaId ?? Guid.NewGuid();
            Data.Status = Status.INIT;
            Data.LogRecordId = Extensions.CreateLogRecordId();

            await Bus.SendLocalWithHeader(new CreateLogCompleteCommand() { SagaId = Data.Id, LogRecordId = Data.LogRecordId });

//SendSMSSaga 
protected override void CorrelateMessages(ICorrelationConfig config)
        {
            config.Correlate(x => x.SagaId, y => y.Id);
            config.Correlate(x => x.SagaId, y => y.Id);
        }
//SendEmailSaga
 protected override void CorrelateMessages(ICorrelationConfig config)
        {
            config.Correlate(x => x.SagaId, y => y.Id);
            config.Correlate(x => x.SagaId, y => y.Id);
        }
```

Then I get the following exception:

5 unhandled exceptions: 13.07.2016 10:26:30 +02:00: System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'Unipluss.Sign.Notification.Queue.Saga.Email.SendEmailSagaData' cannot be converted to type 'Unipluss.Sign.Notification.Queue.Saga.SendSMSSagaData'.

Any tips on what I'm doing wrong?
I've tried both the SQL and the new AzureStorage saga implementations.

Comment: I'm afraid this is a bug - I guess I never imagined one would hit multiple saga instances of different types with a single message.......

Comment: I've raised it as an issue here: https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/issues/486 it'll be fixed some time tomorrow - I hope you can get by until then

Comment: Thanks allot, I can wait until tomorrow

Comment: Hi Rune, I've tried to reproduce the issue locally without any luck - could you maybe see if you could reproduce the issue in a small code sample (or a failing test ;)) that you could send to me?

Comment: I've reproduced it in this sample: https://gist.github.com/runes83/194298531a1d2cade728fc7ee8c8cfe8

Two sagas, and one external handler that both of them use. Used SQL transport and Autofac

Comment: Did you manage to get the information you (@mookid8000) needed from my sample ?

Comment: Yes I did, thanks to your thorough reproduction! I could trace it down to a subtle bug that some (most, actually) saga persisters were prone to that would NOT include the saga data's type in their criteria when correlating by the saga data ID....

Comment: I will release 0.99.68 with a fix as soon as the build server stops crunching

Comment: Will the new release 0.99.68 fix the bus in all saga persisters?

Comment: Yes it will be fixed in all of them :)

Comment: Good thanks for quick assistance in this, Rebus is now a important part of our service. It's good to know there is such a devoted person behind it :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, and it works for all saga storages(*).

You need to keep in mind though that each saga's data is updated separately, so if e.g. the last update experiences a `ConcurrencyException`, the message is rolled back and will be received again.

If this can cause issues for you, you should be sure to make your sagas idempotent.

---

(*) At the time when Rune asked the question it did NOT work as it should. There was a subtle bug in Rebus versions < 0.99.68 that would not include the saga data's type in the criteria when correlating by ID.

This would not be a problem in most cases, because it required multiple saga handlers to handle the same message in order to expose the bug.

It has been fixed in 0.99.68 for all the affected saga persisters.

Comment: when is a ConcurrencyException thrown? What can cause that?

Comment: Rebus throws a `ConcurrencyException` when a conflict is detected when updating the saga data. It uses the `Revision` field of the saga data to implement optimistic concurrency.

Comment: is there something missing in your previous comment?

Comment: It was to long I had to update the original question